# Showing relevant songs based on user data

Tags: sql, algorithm, database-schema

I have this app where I have the genre of music that the user is liking and whenever a user listens to a song he rates it.I want to show them the most relevant songs that the users might like.How do I carry on the database schema?What all data should I take from a user and how to get the most relevant song for the particular user?
Clear Explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very active field of research known as [recommender systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system). If you wish to deal with it seriously, database design is only a first step; you will need to think about a suitable algorithm etc. Your question was specifically about the database schema, so I recommend the following readings:

- [RecDB in Action: Recommendation Made Easy in
  Relational Databases](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol6/p1242-sarwat.pdf)
- [Recommender system datastructures](http://www.cs.carleton.edu/cs_comps/0607/recommend/recommender/datastructures.html)

Comment: Any resources that you would recommend for the suitable algorithm?

Comment: @TarunPothulapati I would start with the following link: https://www.quora.com/Which-algorithms-are-used-in-recommender-systems. There is also a specialization on Coursera if you want to dig deeper: https://www.coursera.org/learn/recommender-systems

Answer (score 1):

Are you recommending the user songs based on his ratings only? In that case, you might need every user in your database to rate at least a few songs. If a user has not yet rated any songs (maybe he signed up for your application recently), you will not be able to recommend him any song. This problem, is called "The Cold Start Problem".

Coming to the question, you can group songs by either genre, artist, album, year or you can take any combination of these parameters. So, your Songs table will have these values along with name of the song, and probably a unique ID. Users table can be as small as UserID and name or you can include his age, location so that you can recommend him songs based on other user's likings with similar age and location.

There would also be a User-Song map table that contains the ratings that every user gives different songs (one-to-many mapping). This table can be used to find a user's favourite song(s)